# Rails redirecting to index with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, parameters

I have this example on gist https://gist.github.com/980828

What I am doing is showing an index page of a conversation between to user_ids, so the index page filters out the right user names.

at the bottom of that page i have a reply-to box and it goes to the create action.

the create action works correctly and saves the model, but i'm trying to then go back to the index page for the conversation but i get an error as the params seem to get lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of explicitly redirecting to the index action, you can redirect to `:back`.

```
redirect_to :back
```

Doing this would take the user back to the index action with the params intact.

Comment: This returns just a HTTP instructions for your browser, asking it to issue a new request for given address. So, yes, the page will be rendered again (unless the page has been cached, but by default it should not be).

Answer (score 0):

I feel its because you are not passing the params[:other_users] from your form to create method.
I am not sure about haml syntax but if you want to pass params[:other_user] from your form to create method, you can use form_tag.
I have used it many times.
Alternatively, you can create a temp table and store value of params[:other_user] in that table when you are in action 'new' and retrieve it when you are in action 'create'.

Hope this helps!
cheers.